# Take the value of a label from a dictionary and separate it into different variables

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with Excel VBA and I have a dictionnary called "dico" who contains 3 keys with differents values, like this example :

Dico 2

Sum for 'Fonctionnel' is `a1 b2 c3 a4 b5 c6 a7 b8 c9 a10 b11 c12 a19 b20 c21 a22 b23 c24`

Sum for 'Securite' is `a13 b14 c15 a16 b17 c18 a31 b32 c33 a34 b35 c36`

Sum for 'Technique' is `a25 b26 c27 a28 b29 c30`

I want for each keys, to have 3 variables regrouping the values with the same type, for example :
I want to have for Fonctionnel :

```
allA = a1 a4 a7 a10 a19 a22
allB = b2 b5 b8 b11 b20 b23
allC = c3 c6 c9 c12 c21 c24
```

For the moment, I have this code :

```
Sub groupByTypo()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, dict, v, k

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set dict2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    'get the input range for the labels
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range(.Range("C1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        'if there's a label, add to the count
        If Len(v) > 0 Then dict(v) = dict(v) + c.Offset(0, -1).Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then dict2(v) = dict2(v) + c.Offset(0, -2).Value
    Next c

    'output the counts
    Debug.Print "Dico 1"
    For Each k In dict
        Debug.Print "Sum for '" & k & "' is " & dict(k)
    Next k

    Debug.Print "Dico 2"
    For Each k In dict2
        Debug.Print "Sum for '" & k & "' is " & dict2(k)
    Next k

End Sub
```

And I have this Excel file :

[image: excel file]

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the complexity of what you are doing, I would approach things a bit differently.

- I will use a VBA array which can read the range in a single operation. It will increase the speed of calculations significantly compared with reading/writing to/from the worksheet.
- I will create a class object, which will hold a Dictionary that collects the different tags, organized by their initial non-numeric values
- I also used early-binding for the dictionary, so as to make use of Intellisense.
- Then it's just a matter of sorting things out at the end to get some kind of useful display.

If still available, the late Chip Pearson's [Introduction to classes](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx) is a useful reference.

**Class Module**

***Rename*** the module `varTypes`

```
Option Explicit
Private pSUM As Long
Private pdTags As Dictionary
Private Col As Collection

Public Property Get SUM() As Long
    SUM = pSUM
End Property
Public Property Let SUM(value As Long)
    pSUM = value
End Property

Public Property Get dTags() As Dictionary
    Set dTags = pdTags
End Property
Public Function adddTagsItem(value As String)
    Dim sKey As String
    Dim I As Long

For I = 1 To Len(value)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(value, I, 1)) Then
        sKey = Left(value, I - 1)
        Exit For
    End If
Next I

If dTags.Exists(sKey) Then
    dTags(sKey).Add value
Else
    Set Col = New Collection
    Col.Add value
    dTags.Add key:=sKey, Item:=Col
End If

End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pdTags = New Dictionary
        pdTags.CompareMode = TextCompare
    Set Col = New Collection
End Sub
```

**Regular Module**

```
Option Explicit
Sub groupByTypo()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Dim clVT As varTypes
    Dim sKey As String
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim vSrc As Variant
    Dim v, w, x
    Dim S As String

    Set dict = New Dictionary
        dict.CompareMode = TextCompare

    'get the input range for the data
    'Read into array for fastest processing
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6")
        vSrc = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
    End With


'Organize in dictionary
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
Set clVT = New varTypes
    With clVT
        sKey = vSrc(I, 3)
        v = Split(vSrc(I, 1))
        For Each w In v
            If Not dict.Exists(sKey) Then
                .adddTagsItem CStr(w)
                dict.Add key:=sKey, Item:=clVT
            Else
                dict(sKey).adddTagsItem CStr(w)
            End If
        Next w
    End With
    dict(sKey).SUM = dict(sKey).SUM + vSrc(I, 2)
Next I

'extract the results
For Each v In dict.Keys
    For Each w In dict(v).dTags
    S = ""
        For Each x In dict(v).dTags(w)
            S = S & " " & x
        Next x

Debug.Print v, dict(v).SUM, S

    Next w
Next v

End Sub
```

**Output**

```
Fonctionnel    10            a1 a4 a7 a10 a19 a22
Fonctionnel    10            b2 b5 b8 b11 b20 b23
Fonctionnel    10            c3 c6 c9 c12 c21 c24
Securite       5             a13 a16 a31 a34
Securite       5             b14 b17 b32 b35
Securite       5             c15 c18 c33 c36
Technique      18            a25 a28
Technique      18            b26 b29
Technique      18            c27 c30
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The problem with this solution is that if I regroupe into only one dictionary all my value, I can't know which label any triplet belongs to.
Example :
I can't know if the triplet (a25, b26, c27) is for the label Fonctionnel, or Technique, or Securite.

Comment: @alain Huh? What does my answer have to do with *regrouping into only one dictionary*? Did you even try the code?

Comment: Yes I tried your code and I have in the new dictionary, for the tag allA for example, a1 a4 a7 a10 a13 a16 a19 a22 a25 a28 a31 a34. But here we have the value for the label Fonctionnel, Technique and Securite.
But for my application I need to be able to distinguish which label the values come from

Comment: @alain OK, I misunderstood your request. I will redo this later today.

Comment: @alain Take a look at my revised answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and thanks for taking the time to respond ! This is a good solution !